# How to screen capture a winform hidden behind another winform?

Tags: .net, winforms, screen-capture, delphi-prism

I need to screen capture a winform that is either behind or in front of another window and nothing else.

I am able to screen capture a winform but it basically captures anything and everything in that area.

Here is how I screen capture.

```
method ControlWin.capturescreen;
begin
        var myGraphics := self.CreateGraphics;
        var memoryGraphics := self.CreateGraphics;
        var s := self.Size;
        ControlScreen := new Bitmap(s.Width, s.Height, myGraphics);
        memoryGraphics := Graphics.FromImage(ControlScreen);
        memoryGraphics.CopyFromScreen(self.Location.X, self.Location.Y, 0, 0, s);
end;
```

Here is how it looks:

[image]

Any hints or clues in C# or delphi-prism will be greatly appreciated. Thanks,

Comment: You need X-ray specs.  You might get a set from the form's DrawToBitmap() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does the trick in C#.

_onTopForm is a second form with TopMost set to true. Place it over Form1.

Click the button and the screenshot of Form1 is written to disk. _onTopForm will not be in the screenshot.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    readonly OnTopForm _onTopForm = new OnTopForm();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _onTopForm.Show();
        _onTopForm.TopMost = true;
    }

    private void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
        DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(Point.Empty, bmp.Size));

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("C:\\temp\\screenshot.jpeg", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            bmp.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}

public partial class OnTopForm : Form
{
    public OnTopForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: James, your example is fantastic. It actually does what I am looking for. Thanks.